# Calling Action method with parameter through ajax call in my custom function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I want to call action method with parameter in my custom function through ajax call.But this will not call my action method.So how can i call my action method in this way.
Here is the code :

```
<script>
function myFunction(e,ids)
{
    var qty = e.value;
    if (qty == null) {
        alert("current null : " + qty + " : id - " + ids);
    }
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:'/MyController/MyActionMethod/Parameter1/Parameter2',
     success: {
          alert("success")
     }

    });

}
</script>
```

My action method is like :

`[HttpPost]

 public ActionResult MyActionMethod(int parameter1,int parameter2){}`

Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to get `'/MyController/MyActionMethod/Parameter1/Parameter2'` to work you would need to setup a custom route.

```
var Parameter1 = '';
var Parameter2 = '';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'/MyController/MyActionMethod?parameter1=' + Parameter1 + '&parameter2=' + Parameter2,
    success: {
        alert("success")
    }
});
```

Another method is to include a `data` argument:

```
var Parameter1 = '';
var Parameter2 = '';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:'/MyController/MyActionMethod',
    data: {
        parameter1: Parameter1,
        parameter2: Parameter2
    },
    success: {
        alert("success")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have custom route for this purpose

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "RouteName", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}",  // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param1 = "", param2 = "" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Now try with your ajax request

```
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url:'/MyController/MyActionMethod/Parameter1/Parameter2',
             success: {
                  alert("success")
             }

        });
```